# How to append elements dynamically with styles in angular5

Tags: angular

I'm trying to append elements dynamically when I click a button.
Actually when I click a button, elements append well.
But the problem is that function and style is not worked.
My code is below.

*P.S. I'm using angular5*

***HTML***

```
<table style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
    <tbody #tContent>
        <!-- I want to append element in here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
    <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addTbody()">click here</button>
```

***TS***

```
    addTbody() {
    ???
}
```

Comment: Haha I know but I'm already using angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is, In the Angular way:

> Component side

```
rowData = [];

addTbody() {
    rowData.push({
        name : 'something',
        age : '15',
        ...
    });
}
```

> Template side

```
<table style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let row of rowData'>
            <td> {{ row.name }} </td>
            <td> {{ row.age }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addTbody()">click here</button>
```

> Try to avoid jQuery as much as possible,while learning Angular

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I want to append input field instead of data, what should I do? My question was it actually.

Comment: if I append input field, then it doesn't work well. I edited my post. Please check it out.

Comment: @MingyuJeon, in that case you need to read : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: I reverted and asked another question.
Here's the link. TY
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47322274/how-to-append-input-field-dynamically-with-styles-in-angular5