# How to append input field dynamically with styles in angular5

Tags: angular

I'm trying to append elements dynamically when I click a button.
Actually when I click a button, elements append well.
But the problem is that function and style is not worked.
My code is below.

*P.S. I'm using angular5*

***HTML***

```
<table style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
    <tbody #tContent>
        <!-- I want to append element in here -->
    </tbody>
</table>
    <button type="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addTbody()">click here</button>
```

***TS***

```
    addTbody() {
    // I want append below code whenever I click.
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 30px">
        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon" (click)="alert('$event')">
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 30px">
        <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon" (click)="test2(file)">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding: 30px">
          <input  placeholder="image Info" type="text" size="25">
      </td>
      <td style="padding: 30px">
          <input placeholder="image Info" type="text" size="25">
      </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

> Component side :

```
this.rows = [];

addTbody() {
    this.rows.push(1);
}
```

> Template side :

```
<table style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor='let row of rows'>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 30px">
                    <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon" (click)="alert('$event')">
                </td>
                <td style="padding: 30px">
                    <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/x-icon" (click)="test2(file)">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 30px">
                    <input  placeholder="image Info" type="text" size="25">
                </td>
                <td style="padding: 30px">
                    <input placeholder="image Info" type="text" size="25">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Link to **[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-add-tr)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. But, this code occur error this, "If 'ngTemplate' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module."

Comment: Sorry typo please change it to `ng-template`, try again.

Comment: Hmm... now error doesn't happened but nothing appended when I clicked a button.

Comment: Did you clicked on button ?

Comment: Yes, I did. What does the meaning of 1 in the this.rows.push()?

Comment: @MingyuJeon, just used array for looping pupose , updated answer use `ng-container` , and also added working link.

Comment: error occured ERROR TypeError: _co.alert is not a function

Comment: @MingyuJeon, alert will not work this way, make function from component side , please check demo, updated the code.

Comment: @MingyuJeon, I hvan't added that, it's default from stackblitz

Comment: I see, it's working! Thank you so much! you made my day

Comment: @MingyuJeon, will you please also upvote the answer?

Comment: ohh Sure, I did :D